# Limitations of unconditional quantile regressions?

Tags: quantile-regression

I've been reading that conditional quantile regression may yield results that are not interesting or generalizable in a policy context, and that unconditional quantile regressions (UQR) are a better way to go.

However, for a better critical understanding of the two approaches, can anyone tell me what are some of the limitations of UQR (with references)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the biggest limitation using UQR is that it can only be used to obtain global effects.
In other words, you can identify how a change in a characteristic will affect a specific individual or group of individuals. What you analyze is:
what would happen if EVERYONE in the population will experience a change in characteristics? In specific, what would happen with the distribution of the outcome if characteristics distribution change? and how is this translated in terms of the quantiles?